# Translate assembly instructions to c++

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, zero-extension

I am having trouble translating the below assembly in to c++

```
MOVZX EAX, DX
```

Where EDX is a 32bit register. I need to get the lowest 16 bits(DX).

I've tried the following:

```
unsigned edx = 0x123ABCDE;
unsigned dx = (edx>>16) & 0xff;
```

I expect to get an the value of BCDE stored in dx, but it's gone a bit wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Big Endian or Little Endian?  Makes a big difference.

Comment: Is the wrong value happen to be 0x123A?

Comment: "gone a bit wrong" What does that mean? Are you getting EDCB or 123A perchance?

Comment: `unsigned eax = edx & 0xffff;`

Comment: Actually, MOVZX moves the 16 bit value in DX into the 32 register, EAX, complete with Zero extension. As stated here: http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/movzx.htm

Comment: Thanks for all your help. @Michaels solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze your code step by step.
`unsigned edx = 0x123ABCDE;`
Nothing unusual.

Let's break up the next statement according to order of evaluation.
`(edx >> 16)` -- right shift by 16 bits.
This is right shifting by 2 bytes or 4 hex digits.
Answer should be 0x123A.

Now, let's keep the right most 8 bits (ANDing with 0xFF):
`0x123A & 0xFF == 0x3A`

The result should be 0x3A in the variable `dx`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This explanation along with Michael's comment has helped me find where I went wrong and understand the solution. eax = edx & 0xffff gives me 0xBCDE where edx=0x123bcde

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click on the check mark.